# Prevent .NET config file being overwritten during install

Tags: .net, windows-installer, app-config, installshield

I'm using InstallShield 2010 Express to install a .NET WinForms app. The latest InstallShield project is a major upgrade, so I've used the Upgrade Paths section to allow upgrades from earlier versions of my app.

The problem is that config settings made during the initial install (written to Program Files\MyCompany\MyApp\myapp.exe.config) are being overwritten when installing the latest upgrade. This means that the user has to make all of the config settings again - not good.

In the InstallShield project, myapp.exe.config is set to use [Windows Installer Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599%28VS.85%29.aspx). I've even tried setting the create/mod date of myapp.exe.config very old (1/1/1999) so that it shouldn't overwrite the file on the target system.

Other than this the installer works fine. How can I prevent this file from being overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

set condition at isxmlinstall in sequence with "NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH"
isxmlinstall  is function for upgrade xml will not launch when upgrade.

Comment: Could you please re-word this answer? It is very unclear what you are trying to say without punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Check the attributes of the .config file in the installer, if its marked as a **key** item and the user has modified it since it was installed the system will use the MSI to replace it believing it to be damaged and in need of repair.

Comment: MSI compares the create and last modified dates to determine whether a non-versioned file should be overwritten. Depending what InstallShield does to the xml file during install you could have a big problem here - effectively the file won't ever get overwritten if gets edited after it's been laid down.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Installsheild have a "before_install" script section? You could copy the existing config file and once the installation is complete overwrite the new one.

Comment: Yes that would be possible however I was hoping that Windows Installer would handle this itself. In the documentation it states:

"Date—If the modified date of a file already present on the target machine is later than the creation date of that file, the file is not overwritten. This rule protects user preference files from being wiped out during an upgrade or reinstallation."

Comment: Not really sure. :( I've run into a few quirks in my limited experience with installshield. Perhaps this is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade() or ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPreviousVersion()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade.aspx